# 0x-API: parsing bytecode

Tags: 0x

I'm using the 0x API on my smart contract.

Is there any available API/tool to parse the bytecode from the 0x API ?

That would enhance my productivity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes their is way you can decode.

```
    struct _0xSwapDescription {
    address inputToken;
    address outputToken;
    uint256 inputTokenAmount;
}
```

and then you can pass 0x api data to following line

```
            ( _0xSwapDescription memory swapDescriptionObj) = abi.decode(_0xData[4:], (_0xSwapDescription));
```

In Most cases it will solve this . But if 0x is trying to run feature like function sellTouniswap or sellToPancakeswap. then above will not return correct error.

Answer (score 0):

We've also built a tool called 0x-debug that is quite helpful for ABI decoding calldata returned by the 0x API: https://github.com/0xProject/0x-debug